# Hidden input field

Tags: javascript

I have an array with 8 elements defined within a script.

I'd like to know how I can pass all the values of this array to a single hidden element.

Pls help.

```
<script ='text/javascript'>

function abc(){

var arr= new Array(8);
for (var i=0; i<8;i++)
{
arr[i]= ...;
}
</script>
<input type="hidden" id="arrs" name="arrs" value= ? >
```

Comment: Please explain why you are trying to do it in a *single* input element and what technology you use at the server end.

Comment: @Tomalak : I will have to access this input hidden element in another js later on using document.forms.element('')..so thought it would be easier using a single element. If thats not possible, then pls let me know, how I can do it using multiple hidden elements..thnx

Comment: Don't use `new Array(8)`. Just do `var arr = [];`. There is no need to initialize the length of the array.

Answer (score 1):

you can join them with comma `','`

```
$('#arrs').val(arr.join(','));
```

Comment: i think he needs solution in JavaScript not in JQuery.

Comment: array.join is also function  in javascript, only need to do getelementbyid like @harry do

Answer (score 1):

From the comments on the question itself

> I will have to access this input
>   hidden element in another js later on
>   using `document.forms.element('')`. so
>   thought it would be easier using a
>   single element.

It would be easiest to not use any form element *at all*. Not sure why you want to take such a detour. You have a JavaScript variable, you can use that directly in "another script later on":

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="firstScript">
  function abc(){
    var arr = [];
    for (var i=0; i<8; i++) {
      arr.push(...);
    }
    return arr;
  }

  var myArray = abc();
</script>

<!-- time passes, but we're still on the same page... -->

<script type="text/javascript" id="anotherScript">
  doSomethingWith(myArray);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
<script>
    function a(){
        var arr= new Array(8);
        for (var i=0; i<8;i++)
        {
            arr[i]= i;
        }
        document.getElementById('d').value = arr;
        alert(document.getElementById('d').value);
    }
</script>
<input id="d" type="hidden" />
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:a();" value="A" />
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the values are only strings or integers, you can try joining them with a seperator not present in your input:

```
document.getElementById("arrs").value = arr.join("###");
```

And you can do

```
myArr = document.getElementById("arrs").value.split("###");
```

To retreive that array back.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, guys! I really appreciate it.My code is finally working.:) Here's what I did, in case you're curious.

Comment: <script ='text/javascript'>  function abc(){  var arr= new Array(8); for (var i=0; i<8;i++) { arr[i]= ...;document.getElementById("arrs"+i).value=arr[i]; } </script> <input type="hidden" id="arrs_0" name="arrs_0" value= "" ><input type="hidden" id="arrs_1" name="arrs_1" value= "" > and so on. The value field remains "" and returns the arr value at runtime.

Comment: @unos33 You should look at the second answer, provides a much cleaner solution!